# how to make join table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, join

I have two table in same database in mysql. 'answer' table and 'return' table.

I want to join two tables to create a new type of table.

I've tried many times to create the bottom desired join table, but failed.

**AnswerTable**

```
seqAnswer question1 question2 question3
1         3         2         3
2         4         1         2
3         1         3         4
```

**ReturnTable**

```
id seqreturn question1 question2 question3
1  3         2         3         1 (X,O,X)
2  1         2         2         1 (X,O,X)
3  2         4         3         1 (O,X,X)
4  1         3         2         4 (O,O,X)
5  3         1         3         1 (O,O,X)
6  3         1         3         2 (O,O,X)
```

question3's (OX,OX,OX) is not actually inserted into the Returntable.just to ask questioin

I want to lay out specific join table. 
 **How do I get below  join table?**

**Desired Join table**

```
Test Number question1 question2 question3 Total
1           1         2         0         2
2           1         0         0         1
3           2         3         1         3
```

Comment: You need to explain how your expected output is derived from your input tables.

Comment: @Nick // I want to make **Desired Join table** at the bottom of the text..
I've tried many times..., but it keeps failing.

Comment: On the first record, I suspect that the answer should be `(X,O,X)` instead of `(X,O,O)`, since the answer given for question3 is not correct (`1` instead of  `3`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to count how many good answers were received for each question. This can be solved with conditionl aggregation, as follows:

```
select
    a.seqAnswer test_number,
    sum(a.question1 = r.question1) question1,
    sum(a.question2 = r.question2) question2,
    sum(a.question3 = r.question3) question3,
    count(*) total
from AnswerTable a
inner join ReturnTable r on r.seqReturn = a.seqAnswer
group by a.seqAnswer
order by test_number
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbe5b924c090d5b5f7c1cf6c9440b829)**:

```
test_number | question1 | question2 | question3 | total
----------: | --------: | --------: | --------: | ----:
          1 |         1 |         2 |         0 |     2
          2 |         1 |         0 |         0 |     1
          3 |         2 |         3 |         0 |     3
```

Comment: And it doesn't match the desired result

Comment: Yep, it could be.

Comment: @GMB : I am a question writer. That's exactly the answer I want. thanks teacher GMB!!

Comment: Welcome @jhyyk! Happy that it helped. For your next question, you might try to be a little more descriptive about your logic... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

using a `subquery` will get what you need and add those each question total

```
select t1.* 
    , iif(q1 >= 1, 1, 0) + iif(q2 >= 1, 1, 0) + iif(q3 >= 1, 1, 0) as Total
from
    (select seqreturn
        , count(question1) as q1
        , count(question2) as q2
        , count(question3) as q3
    from tableA
    group by seqreturn) t1
```

Comment: And iif is not a mysql/mariadb construct (to the best of my knowledge)